Which of the following values can $ \frac{5x^{3}yz}{x^{5}+y^{5}+z^{5}} $ NOT take?
Consider the expression:
$$ \frac{5x^{3}yz}{x^{5}+y^{5}+z^{5}},$$
which is defined for $x > 0$, $y> 0$, and $z> 0$.
Which of the following values cannot be taken by the expression?
$A)1 \quad B)2  \quad C)\sqrt[4]{2} \quad D)\sqrt[5]{25} \quad E)\sqrt[4]{9}$

My approach to the above question;
I used AM-GM Inequality
$x^{5},y^{5},z^{5},1,1 \implies x^{5}+y^{5}+z^{5}+1+1 \ge 5 \cdot \sqrt [5]{x^{5} \cdot y^{5} \cdot z^{5} \cdot 1 \cdot 1} \implies$
$x^{5}+y^{5}+z^{5}\ge 5xyz-2  \implies x^{2} \cdot \frac{5xyz}{5xyz-2} $
But I couldn't reason from here on. What is the correct approach?

By the AM-GM inequality, we know
$$\frac {{x}^{5}}{3} + \frac {{x}^{5}}{3} + \frac {{x}^{5}}{3} + {y}^{5} + {z}^{5} \ge 5 \cdot \sqrt[5] {\frac {{x}^{5}}{3} \cdot \frac {{x}^{5}}{3} \cdot \frac {{x}^{5}}{3} \cdot {y}^{5} \cdot {z}^{5}} = \frac {5 {x}^{3} y z}{\sqrt[5] {27}}.$$
Therefore,
$$\frac {5 {x}^{3} y z}{{x}^{5} + {y}^{5} + {z}^{5}} \le \frac {5 {x}^{3} y z}{5 {x}^{3} y z \, / \sqrt[5] {27}} = \boxed {\sqrt[5] {27} \,}.$$
In your case $2 > \sqrt[5] {27}$, so it is impossible. (Actually, you could have guessed it since it is the maximum value among the five provided.)

We can write:
$$\frac{5x^3yz}{x^5 + y^5 + z^5} = \frac{5\frac{yz}{x^2}}{1 + \frac{y^5}{x^5} + \frac{z^5}{x^5}}$$
and substitute $a = y/x, b = z/x \quad(a,b > 0)$ to get:
$$\frac{5ab}{1 + a^5 + b^5}$$
Let's check, when:
$$\frac{5ab}{1 + a^5 + b^5} = \gamma \iff \gamma a^5 + \gamma b^5 +\gamma - 5ab = 0 \quad (\gamma > 0)$$
has a solution in $(a,b)$.
By examining the function $f(a,b) = a^5 + \gamma b^5 +\gamma - 5ab$ for $a,b > 0$ we see that it has a minimum at $(a,b) = (1/\sqrt[3]{\gamma}, 1/\sqrt[3]{\gamma})$, so:
$$f_{\min}  = f(1/\sqrt[3]{\gamma}, 1/\sqrt[3]{\gamma}) = \gamma - \frac{3}{\sqrt[3]{\gamma^2}}$$
Now, if $\gamma - \frac{3}{\sqrt[3]{\gamma^2}} > 0$, our equation does not have a solution, and when $\gamma - \frac{3}{\sqrt[3]{\gamma^2}} \leqslant 0$, the equation has a solution, because $f(a,b)$ is continuous and for large enough $a$ and $b$ we have $f(a,b) > 0$.
Now by checking that criterion we get that, the equation does not have a solution for : $\boxed{B) 2}$
